# pwr.anova.test : increasing power, decreases sample size?

Tags: anova, effect-size, statistical-power

I am trying to calculate how many samples I need for an ANOVA with 2 groups, effect size of 0.3, significance of 0.05 and power of 0.8.

'''pwr.anova.test(k=2, f=.4, sig.level =.05, power =.8)

Balanced one-way analysis of variance power calculation

```
          k = 2
          n = 44.58577
          f = 0.3
  sig.level = 0.05
      power = 0.8
```

NOTE: n is number in each group.'''

I tried different effect sizes and when I increase the effect size, 'n' decreases, whereas I would expect that more samples would be required to achieve a greater effect size? I'm confused...am I missing something here?

Comment: When the effect size is huge, how many samples do you really need to see it??

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be confused about some concepts:

- The **effect size** is a (standardized) measure of the magnitude of the phenomenon that you are investigating - in other words, it is a property of the world, not of the statistical test, so it does not change if you increase or decrease your sample size.
- The statistical **power** is instead a property of the statistical test: specifically it is the probability that such a test would reject the null hypothesis if performed in an hypothetical world in which the alternative hypothesis is true. Thus, increasing the sample size does achieve a larger statistical power.

In your code you are telling R to calculate the smallest sample size such that your test achieve a statistical power of 80%, assuming that the effect you are investigating is real and has the specified effect size. It follows that if you *increase* the effect size, then the sample size necessary to achieve 80% power *decreases*.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I was getting confused, now I understand!

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted if it cleared up your doubts.